# How to get a value from a column in a DataView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataview

I have a dataview defined as:

```
DataView dvPricing = historicalPricing.GetAuctionData().DefaultView;
```

This is what I have tried, but it returns the name, not the value in the column:

```
dvPricing.ToTable().Columns["GrossPerPop"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the row for which you want to get the value. I would probably be more along the lines of table.Rows[index]["GrossPerPop"].ToString()

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a `DataRow` to get a value; values exist in the data, not the column headers. In LINQ, there is an extension method that might help:

```
string val = table.Rows[rowIndex].Field<string>("GrossPerPop");
```

or without LINQ:

```
string val = (string)table.Rows[rowIndex]["GrossPerPop"];
```

(assuming the data **is** a string... if not, use `ToString()`)

If you have a `DataView` rather than a `DataTable`, then the same works with a `DataRowView`:

```
string val = (string)view[rowIndex]["GrossPerPop"];
```

Comment: The question was about a dataview not a datarow

Answer (score 3):

@Marc Gravell ....
Your answer actually has the answer of this question.
You can access the data from data view as below

```
string val = (string)DataView[RowIndex][column index or column name in double quotes] ;
// or 
string val = DataView[RowIndex][column index or column name in double quotes].toString(); 
// (I didn't want to opt for boxing / unboxing) Correct me if I have misunderstood.
```

Answer (score 1):

for anyone in vb.NET:

```
Dim dv As DataView = yourDatatable.DefaultView
dv.RowFilter ="query " 'ex: "parentid = 1 "
for a in dv
  dim str = a("YourColumName") 'for retrive data
next
```