# How to passing parameter rowIndex in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, xaml, parameter-passing

Im new to C# and MySQL as well.
In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53442357/show-messagebox-that-contain-sql-data-when-button-clicked-in-c-sharp/53442831?noredirect=1#comment93759464_53442831) of my previous question of how to Show messageBox that contain data from SQL he mentioned about:

> pass in parameter the rowIndex and stringToSearch, when calling Execute method.

and I still don't understand how it works.
Below here is my ViewModel

```
public class VModel
{
    public ICommand Clicked { get; set; }
    public DataView Library { get; private set; }
    public VModel()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=library;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("Select * from movie_list where id_movie = @id_movie", connection);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

        }

        var Library = dt.DefaultView;
        var Clicked = new ClickedCommand(this);
    }

}
```

Click

```
 internal class ClickedCommand : ICommand
{
    private VModel _vModel;
    public ClickedCommand(VModel vModel)
    {
        _vModel = vModel;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
            return true;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var rowIndex = (string)parameter[0];
        var stringToSearch = (string)parameter[1];
        MessageBox.Show(_vModel.Library.[rowIndex][stringToSearch]);
    }

}
```

Xaml

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl Background="#191919" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Library}" Margin="130,0,2,0" BorderThickness="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:Card">
                <Button Margin="0,2,0,0" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Clicked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                <Rectangle RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Width="150" Height="230">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush  x:Name="myImage" ImageSource="{Binding Path=cover}"/>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Label Background="#CC000000" Margin="107,10,0,193" Content="{Binding Path=year}" HorizontalContentAlignment="right" Foreground="White"/>
                                <Label Width="150" Background="#CC000000" Margin="0,203,0,0" Content="{Binding Path=title}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                            </Grid>

                        <Label Visibility="Visible"  Name="lbl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Tag="labl"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

On `var rowIndex = (string)parameter[0];` and `var stringToSearch = (string)parameter[1];` it shows this:

> cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type "object"

And when I change my `[rowIndex]` into `[0]` it says:

> cannot convert from "object" to "string"

Comment: what is type of object? is it a datarow?

Comment: @ArgeKumandan DataView

Comment: Can you add the XAML where is the button of this command?

Comment: What is rowIndex and stringToSearch?

Comment: @ArgeKumandan i updated my question

Comment: @Orwel i dont know exactly but i think row index is Rows and stringtosearch is name of row in mysql?

Comment: CommandParameter="{Binding Path=id_movie}" – And what exactly is your id_movie object?

Comment: @Nidrax oh i should delete those lines

Comment: the idea of this program is to click an image and show messagebox from id value of sql but i can't link the id_value to messagebox

Comment: You need `CommandParameter="{Binding Path=id_movie}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need load all movies in the DataView :

```
public class VModel
{
    public ICommand Clicked { get; set; }
    public DataView Library { get; private set; }
    public VModel()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=library;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from movie_list", connection);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

        }

        var Library = dt.DefaultView;
        var Clicked = new ClickedCommand(this);
    }
}
```

And when you click, you display the title :

```
internal class ClickedCommand : ICommand
{
    private VModel _vModel;
    public ClickedCommand(VModel vModel)
    {
        _vModel = vModel;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
            return true;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var id_movie = (int)parameter;
        var rowIndex = id_movie - 1;
        MessageBox.Show(_vModel.Library[rowIndex]["title"].ToString());
    }
}
```

You can replace `"title"` by other column name of table movie_list.

This solution don't use Sql parameter. Not sure is good.

Comment: it says identifier expected before in .[id_movie]

Comment: now it says cannot convert from object to string in (_vModel.Library[id_movie]["title"]);

Comment: Again revised, can you retry?

Comment: it works, but it mismatched 1 data, example i clicked on A then it show B, B to C,etc..

Comment: Rigth, MySql id begin from 1 and .NET array id begin from 0. Again, I have edited my answer.

Comment: You have selected my answer, thank. If you need more explanation from my code, won't hesitate.

Comment: Appreciate it, sir. Thankfully I understand how your answer work now.